# How to compare dates using Spring Expression Language?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

Can anyone give me any examples of how to compare Dates using Spring Expression Languange (Spel)?

I have searched far and wide and nothing I find seems to fit my purpose. I'm using Java 8 and I have a response Object with a ZonedDateTime field which I somehow need to compare to a string in the form of YYYY-MM-DD -- IE: is before, is after, is equal, etc.

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
HashMap<String, Object> testHash = new HashMap<>();
testHash.put("dateField", zonedDateTime);

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
context.setVariables(testHash);

Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("#dateField > '2016-01-01'");
```

The above is obviously not working. Anyone able to show me an example that does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is the code for date comparison using Java 8 java.time package and Spring Expression Language. Hope this helps.

```
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;
import junit.framework.Assert;

public class TestDateSPEL {

@Test
public void testCompareDate() throws Exception {
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String otherDate = "2010-12-25 12:00";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime zdtOtherDate = ZonedDateTime.parse(otherDate, formatter);
    //SpEL Context
    EvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext(new ZonedDateTimeUtil());
    context.setVariable("dateOne", zonedDateTime);
    context.setVariable("dateTwo", zdtOtherDate);
    //SpEL Parser
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("compareDate(#dateOne, #dateTwo)");
    int value = (Integer) exp.getValue(context);
    //"zonedDateTime" is after "zdtOtherDate"
    Assert.assertEquals(1, value);
  }
}

class ZonedDateTimeUtil {
public int compareDate(ZonedDateTime dateOne, ZonedDateTime dateTwo){
    return dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly of what I'm looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to parse your String to Instant or ZoneDateTime or any TemporalAccessor and then use method compareTo() of interface ChronoZonedDateTime that is extended by TemporalAccessor to compare two dates. [See javadoc for compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#compareTo-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-). Use class [java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse a String to TemporalAccessor. (method parse()). Your code may look like:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
TemporalAccessor ta = dtf.parse(yourDateString);
boolean result = yourZonedDateTime.compareTo(ta);
```

That's a base to start with. Also you can see this article that explains how to parse a String of unknown format into date. It might be helpful.

[Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles)

Comment: There is no reference to SPEL here, this answer does not apply to the question.

Answer (score -4):

Please try this as example I hope that it will help you....

```
DateFormat destDf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date startDate;
Date endDate;
String strDate1="2016-08-09 00:00:00";
String strDate2="2015-11-19 00:00:00";
    startDate = destDf.parse(strDate1);
    endDate = destDf.parse(strDate2);
if(startDate.after(endDate)){
Object Date;
if(startDate.before(endDate))
if(startDate.equals(endDate))

//You can check date in java like this also
Date Date date = new Date();
if(date.getDate()==startDate.getDate() && date.getMonth()==startDate.getMonth() && date.getYear()==startDate.getYear()){
    System.out.println("Date1 is equal Date2");
}
```

Comment: Where is SPEL here?

Comment: The difficult part is using SPEL, yet there's no reference to SPEL in this answer.